# Can't copy characters from pointer to another pointer(both with memory allocated)

Tags: c

I have a program that accepts a char input using argv from the command line. I copy the input argv[1] using strcpy to a pointer called structptr(it goes to structptr->words from struct) where memory has been allocated. I then copy character by character from the memory that the pointer structptr points to another pointer called words that points to memory that has been allocated. After i've copied one character i print that element [c] to make sure that it has been copied correctly(which it has). I then finish copying all of the characters and return the result to a char pointer but for some reason it is blank/null. After each copying of the characters i checked if the previous elements were correct but they don't show up anymore([c-2], [c-1], [c]). Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct StructHolder {
char *words;
};
typedef struct StructHolder Holder;

char *GetCharacters(Holder *ptr){
int i=0;
char *words=malloc(sizeof(char));
for(i;i<strlen(ptr->words);i++){
 words[i]=ptr->words[i];
 words=realloc(words,sizeof(char)+i);
}
words[strlen(ptr->words)]='\0';
return words;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

Holder *structptr=malloc(sizeof(Holder));
structptr->words=malloc(strlen(argv[1]));
strcpy(structptr->words, argv[1]);
char *charptr;
charptr=(GetCharacters(structptr));
printf("%s\n", charptr);

return 0;
```

Comment: You need to use a debugger.

Comment: the resulting pointer that i return doesn't seem to hold what i transferred from ptr->words char by char. If i test during that moment it will show that words[3] prints r for example. If i check anyhting before that nothing will be there. When i return the pointer and try to print charptr in main, i get nothing or null.

Comment: You should do as others suggested, just use 1 malloc and a strcpy.  However, for academic purposes, the error in your code is words=realloc(words,sizeof(char)*(i+2))

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is defined to always be `1`, so no need to use it in a case like this.  You could use `sizeof(*words)` if you are worried about the type changing down the road.

Answer (score 2):

At first I thought this was the problem:

`char *words=malloc(sizeof(char))` is allocating 1 byte (sizeof 1 char).  You probably meant `char *words = malloc(strlen(ptr->words)+1);` - You probably want to null check the ptr and it's member just to be safe.

Then I saw the `realloc`. Your realloc is always 1 char short. When i = 0 you allocate 1 byte then hit the loop, increment `i` and put a char 1 past the end of the realloced array (at index 1)

Also your `strcpy` in main is has not allocated any memory in the holder.

Comment: bad example on my part. I actually removed realloc in my example and just set the size to 100 in malloc and i still get the same problem. As for malloc innitially i wanted to have 1 byte for the first char to be transferred, and then after realloc +1 byte for each additional transfer

Comment: I think the problem is your `strcpy` in main is writing to unallocated memory.

Comment: shoot i'm sorry, i had to re-type everything and i did malloc words from the struct before doing strcpy. Will edit that

Comment: Edit your question to have correct code. The input you used, the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: I am passing the characters from  ptr->words to words correctly right? The & and * sometimes confuses me.

Comment: Can't see any obvious problems with * and &

Answer (score 0):

In these two lines,

```
structptr->words=malloc(strlen(argv[1]));
strcpy(structptr->words, argv[1]);
```

need to add one to the size to hold the nul-terminator. `strlen(argv[1])` should be `strlen(argv[1])+1`.

I think the same thing is happening in the loop, and it should be larger by 1. And `sizeof(char)` is always 1 by definition, so:

```
 ...
 words=realloc(words,i+2);
}
words=realloc(words,i+2); // one more time to make room for the '\0'
words[strlen(ptr->words)]='\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Your description talks about `structptr` but your code uses `struct StructHolder` and `Holder`.

This code is a disaster:

```
char *GetCharacters(Holder *ptr){
    int i=0;
    char *words=malloc(sizeof(char));
    for(i;i<strlen(ptr->words);i++){
        words[i]=ptr->words[i];
        words=realloc(words,sizeof(char)+i);
    }
    words[strlen(ptr->words)]='\0';
    return words;
}
```

It should be:

```
char *GetCharacters(const Holder *ptr)
{
    char *words = malloc(strlen(ptr->words) + 1);
    if (words != 0)
        strcpy(words, ptr->words);
    return words;
}
```

Or even:

```
char *GetCharacters(const Holder *ptr)
{
    return strdup(ptr->words);
}
```

And all of those accept that passing the structure type makes sense; there's no obvious reason why you don't just pass the `const char *words` instead.

Dissecting the 'disaster' (and ignoring the argument type):

```
char *GetCharacters(Holder *ptr){
    int i=0;
```

OK so far, though you're not going to change the structure so it could be a `const Holder *ptr` argument.

```
    char *words=malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Allocating one byte is expensive — more costly than calling `strlen()`.  This is not a good start, though of itself, it is not wrong.  You do not, however, check that the memory allocation succeeded.  That is a mistake.

```
    for(i;i<strlen(ptr->words);i++){
```

The `i;` first term is plain weird.  You could write `for (i = 0; ...` (and possibly omit the initializer in the definition of `i`, or you could write `for (int i = 0; ...`.

Using `strlen()` repeatedly in a loop like that is bad news too.  You should be using:

```
    int len = strlen(ptr->words);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
```

Next:

```
        words[i]=ptr->words[i];
```

This assignment is not a problem.

```
        words=realloc(words,sizeof(char)+i);
```

This `realloc()` assignment is a problem.  If you get back a null pointer, you've lost the only reference to the previously allocated memory.  You need, therefore, to save the return value separately, test it, and only assign if successful:

```
        void *space = realloc(words, i + 2);  // When i = 0, allocate 2 bytes.
        if (space == 0)
            break;
        words = space;
```

This would be better/safer.  It isn't completely clean; it might be better to replace `break;` with `{ free(words); return 0; }` to do an early exit.  But this whole business of allocating one byte at a time is not the right way to do it.  You should work out how much space to allocate, then allocate it all at once.

```
    }
    words[strlen(ptr->words)]='\0';
```

You could avoid recalculating the length by using `i` instead of `strlen(ptr->words)`.  This would have the side benefit of being correct if the `if (space == 0) break;` was executed.

```
    return words;
}
```

The rest of this function is OK.

I haven't spent time analyzing `main()`; it is not, however, problem-free.